# VS Code debugger with TypeScript + Imports

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, vscode-debugger

## Context

I'm new to TypeScript and am converting a small code base from JS. When debugging JS, I always point the debugger to a `debug.js` file outside of `src` so that its contents don't accidentally get deployed. Thus, I've created a `debug.ts` file for this project (inside a `para` directory).

## Problem

I can't get the `import`s right and the debug console says "cannot find module [at whatever import path I use]".

## More Info

I've spent the last 24 hours using Google, YouTube, and SO trying to find the answer. Below is a screen of the file contents and structure for a minimal example. [Here's the repo branch for the same example](https://github.com/jamesTbaker/tsTest/tree/create-debug).
[image: VSCode Screenshot]

## Question

How should I import into `debug.ts` so that the debugger can execute the function call and hit a breakpoint in `function.ts`.